# Upgrade Elasticsearch from 5 to 7

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to upgrade my single node elasticsearch from version 5.30 to 7.2. What is the best possible ways of doing it?

Comment: You might be having mapping types in your index and elastic 7.0 doesn't supports doc type so you have to reconfigure your data accordingly ,such that type can be removed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate or give some references??? thanks for the response:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please follow the elasticsearch official document https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html for upgrading your elasticsearch version.

Some important points to take care from upgrading 5.x to 7.3:

- Elasticsearch can read indices created in the previous major version. If you have indices created in 5.x or before, you must reindex or delete them before upgrading to 7.3.1. Elasticsearch nodes will fail to start if incompatible indices are present.
- Take care of things mentioned in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html#_preparing_to_upgrade

  Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Could you please tell me, which upgrade strategy I need to move ahead with. As per my understanding, I need to reindex before i upgrade to 7.2. But, is there a way I can do  some intermediate upgrade with snapshot/restore method and slowly reach to 7.2?

Comment: Data written in 5 cannot be read in 7. Doing a remote reindex to a new 7.x node / cluster would IMO be the easiest and least risky approach.

Comment: But in my requirement, I have to keep the old data from older version 5.3. How can we do that? What is the possible way??? Somebody please help???

Comment: @DeepakRock777, by default you can't export the data of es 5.x to 7.x as there are breaking changes, what you need to do here is to write some custom adapter which will convert your es 5.3 data compitable with es 7.x.